# Composition in Grails: addTo* in Constructors

Tags: grails, composition, modeling

I have the following simplified model in Grails:

- A `DataBlock` consists of a number of sorted `ConfigPreset` objects.

In ConfigPreset I have

```
static belongsTo = [dataBlock: DataBlock]
```

and the DataBlock class contains:

```
List presets
static hasMany = [presets: ConfigPreset]

DataBlock() {
    addToPresets(new ConfigPreset())
}
```

The overloaded constructor returns: No signature of method: [...].addToPresets() is applicable for argument types: (ConfigPreset) values: [ConfigPreset : null].

But why is my ConfigPreset instance null? If I try to create a DataBlock object in e.g. BootStrap.groovy with an unmodified ctor and call addToPresets(...) on it, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example cannot work.

Specifying `static belongsTo = [dataBlock: DataBlock]` inside `ConfigPreset` means that you cannot create a `ConfigPreset`instance without specifying the `DataBlock` owner.

So basically the following statement

`new ConfigPreset()` will always return `null` unlike

`new ConfigPreset(dataBlock: aDataBlock)` that will return a valid `ConfigPreset` instance.

The method `addToXXX` is basically doing the following :

1. Create the XXX instance (as described below)
2. Add the newly created XXX instance to `this` instance

In your case, it cannot create the `ConfigPreset` (step 1) since the `DataBlock` instance is not yet created (your are in the constructor)

If you want to associate automatically a ConfigPreset whenever you create a DataBlock, you can do it by using Gorm Events, adding a callbalck to [beforeInsert](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) event.

Or you can remove `belongsTo` and `new ConfigPreset()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Grails instantiates your domain classes (and other artifacts) at least once during startup for its initialization code. This happens before the dynamic methods are added, hence the exception. It works in BootStrap since everything's configured at this point. Note that nothing is null - you're just seeing the toString() of the domain class which prints the name and id, and since it's a new instance the id is null.

You can use the beforeInsert callback for this though, see - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping